# ¿Cómo se usa el antepretérito?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones, conjugación, pretérito, pretérito-imperfecto

En clase hemos estado repasando el tiempo pluscuamperfecto. En todos los ejemplos que vimos, usaron el imperfecto del verbo *haber*. Cuando pregunté a mi profesor sobre el pretérito de *haber*, nos dijo que nadie lo usa, y en caso de que alguien sí lo hiciera, parecería muy educado y quizás un poco pretencioso, lo que me hizo pensar que *sí hay* veces en que alguien lo usaría. Entonces, ¿qué significa?

Encontré [un sitio web que dice](http://www.123teachme.com/learn_spanish/haber_as_a_helping_verb):

> The use of the preterite of HABER has been eliminated from modern
> Spanish.
>
> (El pretérito de *haber* ha sido eliminado del español moderno.)

¿Es verdad? ¿Hay veces en que alguien lo usaría?

Nótese que estoy hablando del uso de *haber* como un verbo auxiliar, no con otros usos tales como "hay mesas" (no sé cómo hablar de estos modos de verbos, lo siento).

---

Me di cuenta de que estaba tratando de hablar del tiempo *ante pretérito*. Quiero saber si esto se usa en español hoy en día, si significa lo mismo como el pluscuamperfecto, y si hay algunas connotaciones asociadas, como por ejemplo parecer pretencioso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La forma “hubo + participio” (llamada pretérito anterior o antepretérito) sigue vigente en el español escrito en su **registro culto** y se usa en literatura y en el buen periodismo.

La búsqueda con Google de “cuando hubo terminado” recupera 1.400.000 páginas.

Es verdad que el pretérito anterior se usa muy poco en el habla, pero se oye a veces, en un **registro culto**.

También es verdad que a las personas de bajo nivel cultural este pretérito anterior les puede parecer, más que pretencioso, raro.

Ahí van dos ejemplos de uso que a un nativo le sonarían naturales y le pasarían inadvertidos incluso en el habla:

> “Apenas hubo cerrado la puerta, cuando su hermana llamó de forma
>   insistente.”
>
> “Una vez que hube acabado todo lo que tenía que hacer, me dispuse a
>   salir.”

Comment: Si bien los ejemplos son correctos, no estoy de acuerdo con que suenen naturales. En el habla normal se usaría el pretérito indefinido en ambos casos ("Apenas cerró la puerta...", "Una vez acabé todo..."). Sí es cierto que en el lenguaje escrito es más habitual.

Answer (score 1):

No creo que sea eliminado del español moderno. "Que Hubo" es un saludo informal y jergal. Una búsqueda por el internet me dio unos artículos que usan el pretérito de haber. [Artículo1](http://www.wradio.com.co/noticias/sociedad/el-primer-carro-que-hubo-en-colombia-rodo-en-medellin-la-ciudad-mas-innovadora-del-mundo/20130301/nota/1851391.aspx) [Artículo2](http://www.bbc.co.uk/mundo/ultimas_noticias/2013/03/130301_ultnot_venezuela_homicidios_ap.shtml) [Libro1](http://books.google.com/books?id=51Gn_HHlFjwC&pg=PT53&lpg=PT53&dq=que%20hube&source=bl&ots=DhTFy_N0ar&sig=Lnv3iL797Hw0AWjS5b5iiy0YQvg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4-YyUc6mBIqZiQK-qYGwDA&ved=0CH4Q6AEwCQ) [Libro de gramática](http://books.google.com/books?id=_xFZkaXZrjIC&pg=PA132&lpg=PA132&dq=que%20hube&source=bl&ots=0fpuIA-v8s&sig=opKXBIjwXPrHUN1Yps9f9g719_8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4-YyUc6mBIqZiQK-qYGwDA&ved=0CGYQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=que%20hube&f=false)

En el [libro de gramática](http://books.google.com/books?id=_xFZkaXZrjIC&pg=PA132&lpg=PA132&dq=que%20hube&source=bl&ots=0fpuIA-v8s&sig=opKXBIjwXPrHUN1Yps9f9g719_8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4-YyUc6mBIqZiQK-qYGwDA&ved=0CGYQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=que%20hube&f=false) usa haber como un verbo auxiliar:

> En cuanto hube acabado de limpiar toda la casa, finalicé de cocinar el bizcocho preferido de mi hijo

---

I don't believe the preterit has been eliminated from modern Spanish. "Que Hubo" is a greeting that is a little informal and slang. A quick internet search showed me many articles and books that use the preterit form of haber.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I meant to ask about haber's usage as a helping verb in the preterit tense. I'll update my question.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @beanland, I updated the question to answer your update more directly.

Comment: Gracias por el ejemplo. It looks like the "past anterior" or "antepretérito" is "literary, and even archaic form…rarely used in speech". No voy a tratar usarlo, entonces.

Comment: I would agree, probably not the best for speech

Answer (score 1):

Hay cinco pasados en español y los cuatro están en uso.

Pretérito indefinido: hubo

Pretérito imperfecto: había

Pasado perfecto: ha habido

Pretérito anterior: hubo habido

Pretérito pluscuamperfecto: había habido

Este último, que supongo que es al que te refieres, se sule usar en en frases subordinadas o coordinadas en pasado.

Answer (score 0):

El tiempo pluscuamperfecto usa el verbo *haber* como auxiliar para formarse.  Por ejemplo, la conjugación en primera persona del singular en pluscuamperfecto del verbo *deber* es *había debido*.  Por lo tanto, la conjugación en pluscuamperfecto del verbo *haber* es la siguiente, con su equivalente en inglés:
yo había habido     I have had
tú habías habido    Thou hadst had
él había habido    He had had
nosotros habíamos habido    We had had
vosotros habíais habido    You had had
ellos habían habido    They had had
El verbo *haber* ha ido perdiendo su significado de "tener", para especializarse como verbo auxiliar **de otros verbos**.  Es por eso que las conjugaciones compuestas del verbo *haber* ya no se usan, y [la RAE no las incluye](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/apendices/apendice1.html#n35)